# How to add message body inside SFMC SendEmail API Post?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

We're being asked to send an email through SFMC via [the Messaging: Send Email API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/messageDefinitionSends.html). It does not specify a message body. Where would I add the actual body of the email message?